# Detect consecutive curly brace in JToken

Tags: c#

I have this code below using `JToken`

**Item Value**

> {"clause_type": [
> "Force Majeure - General"
> ]}

```
        var itemJson = "{" + item + "}";
        JObject joItem = new JObject();
        joItem = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(itemJson);
```

above value and code is perfectly working fine.. But sometimes the value has a consecutive `curly brace`

> {{"clause_type": [
> "Force Majeure - General"
> ]}}

when Deserializing it it causes an error `Invalid property identifier character: {. Path '', line 1, position 1`

Is there a way to remove or check the `item` if it has a consecutive `curly brace` and remove it?.

Comment: Fix the json at its source, rather than try to parse invalid json

Comment: If you want to avoid regex, then you can use something like  `while(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item) && item.Trim().IndexOf("{{",0)!=-1) 
  item = new String(item.Skip(1).ToArray());`
It just handles the beginning of the string, the remaining part must be implemented as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @00110001 pointed in the comments, it is recommended to fix the json first. But if you can't , you may use this regex for replacing two or more consecutive curly braces by one:

```
string new_item = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Item, "([{][{]+)" ,"{"), "([}][}]+)" , "}");
```

Comment: Thank you it works. but can you explain the regex even how many times I study it I can't read a regex

Comment: @KiRa I am sorry for answering late. The inner Replace, replaces two or more consecutive '{' with one '{', and the outer one replaces two or more consecutive '}' with one ''}'.